# WEBMIN LDAP authentication: passwd returns "Authentication token manipulation error"

Tags: pam, authentication, ldap, webmin

Update:jan 25 2023
I believe I have sssd and nslcd working properly I also adjusted the pam modules in webmin. I also added db to nsswitch.conf so I checks there first. As of right now I can use things like ldapsearch -x -D cn=bindadmin,ou=People,dc=xxx,dc=com -W to query my db full of user succesfully I can also passwd $USER succesfully and log in with the new password using su -l $USER the only remaining problem I'm having is allowing the user to log into webmin I was hoping since the client is working and passwd changing works it would allow me to log in but when I attempt to change the converted webmin users acl for webmin log in I get the following error in /var/webmin/miniserv.error and this seems to be the only log error msg I get which is preventing my webmin users from logging in. Any thoughts?

Argument "" isn't numeric in numeric ne (!=) at /usr/libexec/webmin/acl/save_unix.cgi line 80.
[25/Jan/2023:11:01:59 -0500] Reloading configuration

I'm trying to setup ldap authentication for unix users to log in and I'm getting the token error. I have ldap users and groups working and I've converted all the unix users to webmin users but I cant get the users to log in or change password with passwd. I configured and enabled sssd.conf but I believe the issue may have to do with PAM files which I have limited experience with any help would be appreciated I'll add a few of the PAM configs along with the `sssd.conf` below. Let me know if you need anything else to help trouble shoot this thank you.

I also cant use anything like ldapmodify or ldapsearch which is because of a misconfigured ldap-client not reaching the server I presume? When I configure ldap-client on webmin with the nslcd.conf file and I use the validate button it returns the following but it doesn't give me the option to run/start the client as it had prior now it only gives me the validate configuration option and both start ldap-client alongside could this be why its not connecting properly?

Error msg when I try ldap search:

```
SASL/GSS-SPNEGO authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information (SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate)

Finding LDAP base for users ..
.. found base dc=xxxx,dc=com.
Connecting to LDAP server ..
.. connected to ldap-primary.ue1.-prod.com

Searching for users ..
.. found 507 users.

Checking Unix users service ..
.. service is setup to query LDAP.

Looking for Unix user bjones ..
.. user found successfully.

Your system has been successfully configured as an LDAP client!
```

Expectations:

- LDAP users and groups functionality working [complete]
- converted unix webmin users log in functionality working [not working]

The following commands works

```
$ id tuser
uid=6469(tuser) gid=6250(gwtest) groups=6250(gwtest),9003(git),9001(softeng)

$ getent passwd tuser
tuser:*:6469:6250:test user:/home/tuser:/bin/bash
```

log msg when I try `passwd tuser`:

```
passwd: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "tuser" does not exist in /etc/passwd
passwd: pam_sss(passwd:chauthtok): Authentication failed for user tuser: 4 (System error)
```

log msg when converted webmin users attempts to log in:

```
pam_unix(webmin:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=10000 ruser= rhost=xxx user=xxx
webmin[8072]: Invalid login as xxxx from xxxx
```

passwdauth:

```
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth required pam_env.so
auth required pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet
auth [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_localuser.so
auth sufficient pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth requisite pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth sufficient pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth required pam_deny.so

account required pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account sufficient pam_localuser.so
account sufficient pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account required pam_permit.so

password requisite pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3
password sufficient pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass
password sufficient pam_sss.so


password required pam_deny.so

session optional pam_keyinit.so revoke
session required pam_limits.so
-session optional pam_systemd.so
session optional pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session required pam_unix.so
session optional pam_sss.so

passwd
#%PAM-1.0
auth include system-auth
account include system-auth
password substack system-auth
-password optional pam_gnome_keyring.so
password substack postlogin

webmin
#%PAM-1.0
auth sufficient pam_ldap.so
auth required pam_unix.so nullok
account sufficient pam_ldap.so
account required pam_unix.so
session sufficient pam_ldap.so
session required pam_unix.so

system-auth
#%PAM-1.0
# This file is auto-generated.
# User changes will be destroyed the next time authconfig is run.
auth required pam_env.so
auth required pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet
auth [default=1 ignore=ignore success=ok] pam_localuser.so
auth sufficient pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth requisite pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth sufficient pam_sss.so forward_pass
auth required pam_deny.so

account required pam_unix.so
account sufficient pam_localuser.so
account sufficient pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_sss.so
account required pam_permit.so

password requisite pam_pwquality.so try_first_pass local_users_only retry=3 authtok_type=
password sufficient pam_unix.so sha512 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password sufficient pam_sss.so use_authtok
password required pam_deny.so

session optional pam_keyinit.so revoke
session required pam_limits.so
-session optional pam_systemd.so
session optional pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077
session [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session required pam_unix.so
session optional pam_sss.so
```

sssd.conf

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, ssh
reconnection_retries = 3
domains = xxxx

[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root,named,nscd

[

[domain/xxx]
access_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = true
chpass_provider = none
debug_level = 3
entry_cache_timeout = 300
enum_cache_timeout = 300
enumerate = true
id_provider = ldap
ldap_access_order = expire
ldap_account_expire_policy = shadow
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = xxxx

ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=bindadmin-sssd,ou=People,dc=xxxx,dc=com
ldap_enumeration_refresh_timeout = 300
ldap_group_member = memberUid
ldap_group_name = cn
ldap_group_object_class = posixGroup
ldap_group_search_base = ou=Groups,dc=xxxx,dc=com
ldap_id_use_start_tls = false
ldap_network_timeout = 3
ldap_pwd_policy = shadow
ldap_schema = rfc2307
ldap_search_base = dc=xxx,dc=com
ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
ldap_tls_reqcert = never
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldap-01.ue1-prod.com
ldap_user_name = uid
ldap_user_object_class = posixAccount
ldap_user_search_base = ou=People,dc=xxxx,dc=com
ldap_user_shadow_expire = shadowExpire
shell_fallback = /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by installing **perl-Authen-PAM** -module (`yum install perl-Authen-PAM`) and updating my webmin pam configuration:

```
auth       required     pam_env.so
auth       sufficient   pam_unix.so likeauth nullok
auth       sufficient   pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
auth       required     pam_deny.so

account    sufficient   pam_unix.so
account    sufficient   pam_ldap.so
account    required     pam_ldap.so

password   required     pam_cracklib.so difok=2 minlen=8 dcredit=2 ocredit=2 retry=3
password   sufficient   pam_unix.so nullok md5 shadow use_authtok
password   sufficient   pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
password   required     pam_deny.so
```

Comment: Nice! Please don't forget to check back after 2 days to [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) your answer :-)